# local stylesheet and scripts not loading JAVA

Tags: java, maven, jsp

I have an application written in JAVA (which I didn't write) and all of the paths were really out of whack for what the standard paths should be, and the app wouldn't build. I'm assuming . I've reorganized the paths to look like this:

```
├── README.md
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── appdomain
│       │           └── runtime
│       │               └── calculation
│       │                   ├── Common
│       │                   │   └── SendGridExample.java
│       │                   ├── Data
│       │                   │   ├── CommonMessages.java
│       │                   │   ├── CommonUtils.java
│       │                   │   └── WorkbookHelper.java
│       │                   ├── Model
│       │                   │   ├── CalculatorProperty.java
│       │                   │   ├── FormHelper.java
│       │                   │   └── ViewHelper.java
│       │                   ├── Utility
│       │                   │   ├── CurrencyUtility.java
│       │                   │   ├── ImageUtils.java
│       │                   │   └── AppUtility.java
│       │                   └── controller
│       │                       └── CalculatorController.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   ├── calculations.xlsx
│       │   ├── css
│       │   │   ├── CustomElement.css
│       │   │   ├── style-sheet.css
│       │   │   └── style1.css
│       │   ├── email_text
│       │   │   └── index.html
│       │   ├── fonts
│       │   │   └── …[font files]…
│       │   ├── images
│       │   │   └── [images].png
│       │   ├── js
│       │   │   ├── customInput.jquery.js
│       │   │   ├── input.js
│       │   │   └── output.js
│       │   └── lang
│       │       ├── messages_en.properties
│       │       └── messages_fn.properties
│       └── webapp
│           ├── WEB-INF
│           │   ├── classes
│           │   ├── jsp
│           │   │   ├── index.jsp
│           │   │   ├── template1.jsp
│           │   │   ├── template2.jsp
│           │   │   └── output.jsp
│           │   ├── log4j.properties
│           │   ├── springmvc-servlet.xml
│           │   └── web.xml
│           └── index.jsp
└── target
```

Now when I build it using maven, upload the war file to the Tomcat Web Application Manager, go to the site (local.app:8080/myapp), the site templates look good and all 3rd party CSS and JS is loaded (jquery, etc...), but none of the javascript and CSS including in the above tree is loaded.

currently the paths in the HTML look like this: classes/css/style-sheet.css
But I've tried every path I can think of and I still get a 404 (e.g. /myapp/WEB-INF/resources/css/style-sheet.css, /myapp/resources/css/style-sheet.css, css/style-sheet.css).
Any idea what needs to happen to get the CSS and JS to load?

Comment: What happen if you move all that stuff to the other project and write the CLI to load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You must move your static web resources (*.html, *.js, *.css, images, etc) to `src/main/webapp`, according to [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Directory `src/main/resources` is aimed to contain static files to be read from Java (like `.properties` files).

Comment: That did the trick. Had to also bump up the heap size on this app. Something seems definitely wrong with it, but at least it's working. Thanks!